# JPA/Hibernate with sql lite - performance

Tags: performance, hibernate, sqlite, jpa, orm

I have a question about JPA/Hibernate performance.

We are building web application, one of the goals is to store questions and their answers. For both of these things we have class hierarchy, and `@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)`.

The questions have references to their answers, every question is stored in some list.

I observed using firebug that when I am adding new question to the list and use `entityManager.merge` I need to wait about one second for response. I think that it is pretty long time to wait for a response for simple add request.

Is it because of the Inheritance strategy, or maybe I shouldn't use `entityManager.merge` and try to write my own query.

Maybe the performance is low because I am using sql lite database (sql lite is used just for testing, on production postgre will be used)?

Or this kind of performance is pretty standard for ORM solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I use sqlite a lot (sometimes even for production) and the performance is sometimes even better than for traditional client server connections.

Maybe you should debug you application and enable logging of the JPA provider you are using to see if in fact the inheritance model is to blame.

But, if you have done the inheritance correctly then I don't think that would be te issue. It would help if you paste the code for how you declare the classes.

I would also look at a profiler if this persists.

Comment: I found out why I had so poor performance. I used `ArrayList` without indexed column, so every add or remove from the collection resulted in Hibernate deleting all from the table and reinserting it again with the new row. Now I am using `Set` to store my objects and everything is ok.